# WebCamTexture Coming Up With All 0s in the First Second or Two

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, webcam

I am using a WebCamTexture and I start it in my `Start` method, then I run another method. I get the pixels using `GetPixels()`, however, they all come up as `(0, 0, 0)`. Is there any fix to this or way I can wait (Unity seems to crash using `while` loops and `WaitForSeconds`). Here is my current Start method:

```
void Start () {

    rawImage = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage> ();
    rawImageRect = rawImage.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();

    webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    rawImage.texture = webcamTexture;
    rawImage.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;

    webcamTexture.Play();

    Method ();

    loadingTextObject.SetActive (false);
    gameObject.SetActive (true);

}

void Method(){

    print (webcamTexture.GetPixels [0]);

}
```

And this prints a `(0, 0, 0)` color every time.

Comment: Hi Dylan.  This is a well-known problem with Unity and webcams.  What you actually have to do is wait ***until a reasonable size is reported***.  In practice you skip frames until yourWebCam.width is bigger than 100.  It is explained fully here  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/773464/webcamtexture-correct-resolution-and-ratio.html

Comment: BTW most people just use NatCam https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/52154 these days.  Unity's webcam software is crap.  it's one of the things they "have not got to yet".  Be prepared to spend weeks working with the webcam.

Comment: Oh okay I'm already doing that somewhere else. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: don't forget to tick an answer.

Comment: That didn't quite work. I had to combine WaitForSeconds, checking to see if a reasonable size is reported, and WaitForEndOfFrame

Comment: Hey, I would strongly avoid use of `WaitForEndOfFrame`; what you could do is just skip another couple of frames after the search completes (So, just go `yield return null` a couple times after waiting.)  Good luck!  Consider just using NatCam, save weeks of work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your webcam stuff in a coroutine then wait for 2 seconds with `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);` before calling `webcamTexture.GetPixels`.

```
void Start () {

    rawImage = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage> ();
    rawImageRect = rawImage.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();

    StartCoroutine(startWebCam());

    loadingTextObject.SetActive (false);
    gameObject.SetActive (true);

}

private IEnumerator startWebCam()
{
    webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    rawImage.texture = webcamTexture;
    rawImage.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;

    webcamTexture.Play();

    //Wait for 2 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    //Now call GetPixels
    Method();

}

void Method(){
    print (webcamTexture.GetPixels [0]);
}
```

Or like Joe said in the comment section. Waiting for seconds is not reliable. You can just wait for the width to have something before reading it.Just replace the

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
```

with

```
while (webcamTexture.width < 100)
{
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: That seems to crash Unity.

Comment: @DylanSiegler Which part crashes Unity? Try to be specific. You can find out by commenting codes from bottom to the top.

Comment: The yield return WaitForSeconds(2)

Comment: @DylanSiegler This is not true. Something else is crashing your Application. Disable or remove all other scrips attached to your GameObjects. Make sure that this is the only script in your Editor. Try it again, if it crashes again, Edit your question and copy and paste all the code in your current script. That I can use to figure out what is causing the crash. Also mention what Unity version you are using in the question Edit.

Comment: I have got it to stop crashing my game, however, this time it simply returns (1, 1, 1). Could I make it yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame?

Comment: @Programmer.  You know, rather than waiting for a small time (2 seconds), skip until it correctly reports a size rather than a silly value. That seems to be the only way to know when it is ready....

Comment: hi @DylanSiegler, there are literally 100s of other things you could be doing wrong that is crashing it.  It is incredibly difficult to use the WebCam properly.  unless you have some truly important reason to use the webCam, I would just forget about it and try another project.

Comment: I found the source of the crash. It just seemed like it was crashing because of the waiting.

Comment: @JoeBlow Webcam returns random values depending on the brightness and the color of the image it is facing.Somestimes, 0,0,0 and that can actually be valid value for a pixel. How do you know if a value is valid or not?

Comment: @DylanSiegler I know the crashing it gone but what was the problem? You said waiting...Which part? Can you post the code that was crashing?

Comment: @Programmer - yeah don't do that, what you loop on is the ***WIDTH***, of all things!  until it reports a reasonable ***SIZE***, it has not started working.  Unity have no call "is it working yet", the only thing that works is to continually check the SIZE until it reports a non-crazy value.  That's the way to go!

Comment: Guys BTW don't forget these days you should surely be putting a webCam **on the UI**, not on a normal scene thing...  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/909967/getting-a-web-cam-to-play-on-ui-texture-image.html

Comment: @JoeBlow He did use UI. He used `RawImage`. Anyways I am struggling to figure out how to do what you said. When you said WIDTH size, are you talking about `webcamTexture.width`? If not, could you comment with a sample code on how to retrieve that info?

Comment: The lag was from me insertion sorting every color in the initial frame. I'll work out how to get that working later.

Comment: @JoeBlow Just saw your comment under his question and I get how to do that. Will update my answer.

Comment: yes .width !  note that you will need the ***ratio coming from the camera*** ... so you need that anyways

Answer (score 0):

Two seconds might be quite alot of time spend waiting when you're grapping the size of the requested image.

The WebCamTexture has a requsted width/height that you can access and it will save the "real" width/height of the texture after calling GetPixels once. We've used the asset called CameraCaptureKit (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673 ) in two projects where we share photos with the users.

The codes used there takes the WebCamTexture and Graps the frames every frame until it returns a width and height of the texture.

In an update function TryDummySnapshot was called until the size was returned properly.

```
// ANDREAS added this: In some cases we apparently don't get correct width and height until we have tried to read pixels
    // from the buffer.
    void TryDummySnapshot( ) {
        if(!gotAspect) {
            if( webCamTexture.width>16 ) {
                if( Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ) {
                    if(verbose)Debug.Log("Already got width height of WebCamTexture.");
                } else { 
                }
                gotAspect = true;
            } else {
                if(verbose)Debug.Log ("Taking dummy snapshot");
                if( tmpImg == null ) {}
                Color32[] c = webCamTexture.GetPixels32();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the second part of my answer with `webcamTexture.width < 100`? He's not taking a snaphot, he wants to be retrieving image from the camera. Destroying Texture will slow things down too.

Comment: I see your point - maybe one of these texture's shouldnt be destroyed but how long does it really take ? I don't know the reason why the first Texture is created and destroyed ( when its greater than 10 ) - I copy pasted the code. How long does it take to destroy the texture ?

Comment: Isnt taking a snapshot the same thing as retriving an image from the camera?

Comment: **1**. If you are constantly receiving pixels from the camera, you shouldn't be creating and destroying Textures. **2**. He's not using Texture2D anywhere in his code. He used RawImage from UI which is the best way to do this without allocating memory.

Comment: The point of my comment is that this problem has been solved. Your answer just about checking width is already done in the second part of my answer. Please read the comments from Joe in my answer. That answered the question you left in my answer.

Comment: 1. Your statement is correct however it doesnt mean much since the textures are less than 10x10 pixels. It could however be optimized.

Comment: 2. Your statement about a rawimage is not allocating memory is not entirely true, RawImage uses a Texture2D to show the content so, which is 1024x1024x4 bytes in size or less depending if you're using a compressed or not. However if you want to just show the running preview onf a webCamTexture on a UI.RawImage you can save "some" memory - you still need to grap the pixels though to get the aspect right.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wait until a size is reported or allocate and the target platform is iOS (iPhone/iPad) it's also possible to write a plugin that gets the size directly from the Camera code in Unity by extending CameraCapture.mm :

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*)connection
{
intptr_t tex = (intptr_t)CMVideoSampling_SampleBuffer(&self->_cmVideoSampling, sampleBuffer, &self->_width, &self->_height);

_staticWebCamTexWidth = self->_width;
_staticWebCamTexWidth = self->_height;

UnityDidCaptureVideoFrame(tex, self->_userData);

if( self.firstFrameCallback!=nil ) {
    [self fireFirstFrame];
}
}
```

self->width / height can be returned in a method added as a plugin method like :

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern int GetWebCamTextureWidth ();

[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern int GetWebCamTextureHeight ();
```

and then in the objc code

```
extern "C" int GetWebCamTextureWidth() { return _staticWebCamTexWidth;  }
extern "C" int GetWebCamTextureHeight() { return _staticWebCamTexHeight;  }
```

This is the solution i came up with for one of iOS social games that uses unity. On Android we fell back on the previously described approach.